# How to balance topical, two classes dataset when one of the topics is too broad and the other is very narrow?

Tags: python, nltk, prediction, text-classification

I have simple prediction, where The dataset is composed from 2300 samples for each class e.i. total = 4600 (binary classification). The first class encompasses all news types except the other class, which is very narrow topic. I have used The [Naive-Bayes classifier](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/naivebayes.html) of NLTK to perform the task, where the classifier takes the samples one-hot-encoded. Although the classifier performed well in test portion of the dataset (94% accuracy), it fails miserably when it classify crawled news (in production).
[image]
My thinking the problem is due to that the two classes are imbalanced in the real word. If this is the reason, then, how to overcome this problem? how to balance my dataset? Assume that I can collect many samples additionally for the broad class(A), but very a few samples for the narrow class(B).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Synthetic Minority Oversampling Technique, SMOTE, to increase the size of the minority class.

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
sm = SMOTE()
x1, y1 = sm.fit_sample(X_train, Y_train)
```

Also, Naive Bayes is not a good algorithm for imbalanced classes, try using Random Forest (without SMOTE) or Gradient Boosted Trees (with SMOTE).

Comment: So SMOTE is  a classifier?

Comment: No, classifiers are Naive Bayes, Gradient Boosted Trees, Neural Networks, SVMs, logistic regression, decision trees, etc. SMOTE is an algorithm that considers Euclidean Distance to create more examples in the minority class following a similar distribution of your existing minority class.

Comment: I have understood the basic concept of SMOTE, but  How to apply SMOTE for samples represented using one-hot-encoding? or I should represent them in different way?

Comment: Then you can use the EM (Expectation Maximization) algorithm.